# Buffer overflow? strncat() in C

Tags: c, char, c-strings, function-definition, strncpy

I'm very new to C, and I want to make a simple program that gets an index of a string from the value, and once it has the index, it removes it from a string. It's causing a buffer overflow error? Pretty sure it's from strcat from searching online but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated! Also please don't use * in your answer, because I don't know how they work, I will learn very soon. (if its required for your answer, explain how you use it in the code please)

heres the code:

```
#include <string.h>

int findIndex(char string[], char substr) {
    for (int index = 0; index < strlen(string); index++) {
        if (string[index] == substr) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void) {
    char howAreYou[9] = "howAreYou";
    char newString[9];

    int index = findIndex(howAreYou, 'o');
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (i != index) {
            strncat(newString, &howAreYou[i], 1);
        }
    }

    printf("new string: %s", newString);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The approach looks wrong to me. You probably need `memmove` instead of `strncat`. [Edit] and show some examples of input and expected output so we can be sure what you actually want. BTW `strncat` is a very weird function, don't use it unless you understand **exactly** what is does

Comment: Note that `strncat` is not really a C string function, because it does not guarantee `'\0'`-terminated string in destination. Easier to use `snprintf` or `strncat` or even `memcpy`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `char howAreYou[] = "howAreYou";` to allow for a terminating zero.
Use `char newString[sizeof howAreYou] = "";` to have the correct size for the array and initialize the array so it is empty before concatenation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int findIndex(char string[], char substr) {
    for (int index = 0; string[index]; index++) {
        if (string[index] == substr) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void) {
    char howAreYou[] = "howAreYou";
    char newString[sizeof howAreYou] = "";

    int index = findIndex(howAreYou, 'o');

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof howAreYou; i++) {
        if (i != index) {
            strncat(newString, &howAreYou[i], 1);
        }
    }

    printf("new string: %s\n", newString);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters you forgot to include the header `<stdio.h>`

It is better to define the array `howAreYou` like

```
char howAreYou[] = "howAreYou";
```

instead of

```
char howAreYou[9] = "howAreYou";
```

otherwise the array does not contain a string.

Correspondingly the array `newString` should be declared like

```
char newString[sizeof( howAreYou )];
```

The array `newString`  does not not contain a string. So the call of the function `strncat` invokes undefined behavior.

Also in general you need to check the return value from the function `findIndex`.

As you are already using standard C string functions and want to remove only the first occurrence of the letter `'o'` then it can be done simply using standard C function `strchr`.

To store one character using the function `strncpy` is silly and inefficient.

For example

```
const char *p = strchr( howAreYou, 'o' );

if ( p == NULL )
{
    strcpy( newString, howAreYou );
}
else
{
    size_t n = p - howAreYou;
    strncpy( newString, howAreYou, n );
    strcpy( newString + n, p + 1 );
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char howAreYou[] = "howAreYou";
    char newString[sizeof( howAreYou )];

    const char *p = strchr( howAreYou, 'o' );

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        strcpy( newString, howAreYou );
    }
    else
    {
        size_t n = p - howAreYou;
        strncpy( newString, howAreYou, n );
        strcpy( newString + n, p + 1 );
    }

    puts( newString );
}
```

The program output is

```
hwAreYou
```

If you want to use your own function `findIndex` then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t findIndex( const char string[], char c )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while (string[i] != '\0' && string[i] != c) ++i;

    return string[i] == '\0' ? -1 : i;
}

int main( void )
{
    char howAreYou[] = "howAreYou";
    char newString[sizeof( howAreYou )];

    size_t n = findIndex( howAreYou, 'o' );

    if ( n == ( size_t )-1 )
    {
        strcpy( newString, howAreYou );
    }
    else
    {
        strncpy( newString, howAreYou, n );
        strcpy( newString + n, howAreYou + n + 1 );
    }

    puts( newString );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to make a function that removes the desired char from your string.
**But make sure to add '\0' (null character) at the last of your string**.

> As when you'll remove one character from the string it's length should be **decremented by one** as all the characters after that position will be shifted to **one position left** so there isn't any need for last character

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int findIndex(char string[], char substr)
{
   for (int index = 0; index < strlen(string); index++)
   {
      if (string[index] == substr)
      {
         return index;
      }
   }
   return -1;
}

// This function removes the desired character from the char array
void removeChar(char string[], int index)
{
   for (int i = index + 1; i < strlen(string); i++)
   {
      string[i - 1] = string[i];
   }
   // Making the last character '\0' (null character) so that string can end here
   string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
   char howAreYou[9] = "howAreYou";

   int index = findIndex(howAreYou, 'o');
   removeChar(howAreYou, index);

   printf("new string: %s", howAreYou);
   return 0;
}
```

Hope it helped! :)